# How to convert a list of dictionary to a table in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

In DolphinDB database, I have a list of dictionaries such as

```
[dict(`a`b, 1 2), dict(`a`b, 11 12), dict(`a`b, 1 12)]
```

. How do I convert it into a table so that each dict is a row in the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
y = [dict(`a`b, 1 2), dict(`a`b, 11 12), dict(`a`b, 1 12)]
each(x->x, y)
```

The above code solved your problem. The lambda function x->x returns the input itself, i.e. a dictionary. The high order function `each` assembles multiple dictionaries into a table.

Comment: s.upload({"ds":ds})
s.run("""
t=each(x->x,ds)
typestr(t)
""")
'ANY VECTOR'

Comment: why not table when upload python list of dict?